# Scheduler control in Kendo UI for Angular Package

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is scheduler control is available in kendo ui for angular package? They said they going to add scheduler control in angular package with 2017 Q2 release, but I couldn't find the scheduler control in Kendo UI For Angular package?

Can I combine Kendo UI for jQuery and Kendo UI for Angular in same project? I need to develop application with angular and I need use scheduler control on the same project.

Comment: Thank you down voting group

Answer (score 1):

No there is not and there is no short term plan. There is long term plan to do it. Details are available [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/).

I am pretty sure they didn't promise scheduler component in Q2 2017.

*Yes you can mix kendo UI for jQuery with kendo UI for Angular. They propose same solution when using [Telerik Reporting](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/angular-report-viewer-system-requirements).*

[Here are documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/) how to mix kendo UI for Angular with kendo UI for jQuery.